# Creating users in dream factory

Tags: api, rest, postman

I was using [dreamfactory](https://www.dreamfactory.com) and was trying to create users with different roles and use those to send requests however those users aren't working for me. The admin users are however. I don't understand why that is.

Below are the steps I've taken;

In the admin console, click the Roles tab then click Create in the left sidebar.

Enter a name for the role and check the Active box.

Go to the Access tab.

Add a new entry under Service Access (you can make it more restrictive later).

set Service = All

set Component = *

check all HTTP verbs under Access

set Requester = API

Click Create Role.

Click the Services tab, then edit the user service. Go to Config and enable 
Allow Open Registration.
Set the Open Reg Role Id to the name of the role you just created.
Make sure Open Reg Email Service Id is blank, so that new users can register without email confirmation.

Save changes.

Then I registered the user incognito mode

I used a google extension rest client called [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to make the request
In postman I used Basic Auth entered the username and password and sent the request

{
  "error": {
    "context": null,
    "message": "Access Forbidden.",
    "code": 403
}

...

Above is the result I got when I use the user I just registered. However when I use the admin username and password, I get the following response.

Status 200 OK

{"resource": [{"name": "_schema"},{"name": "_table"},{"name": "_proc"},{"name":"_func"}]}

which is the result I want for the other users.

Please let me know what I did wrong so I can fix it. Thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have configured my system the same and will walk through the steps. This is done on the [06 Oct 2015 commit](https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/dreamfactory/commit/30d2fc7703bd8445517b8755eb31cdfba247e38c) of DreamFactory 2.0 beta.

First, to register a user:

```
POST /api/v2/user/register
X-DreamFactory-Api-Key: 0d430cc287b5dd88b0f615d2bb69d84ba7201e8d4214fee2eabcc96bcd937d7d

{
  "email": "user@domain.com",
  "first_name": "Basic",
  "last_name": "User",
  "display_name": "Basic User",
  "new_password": "password"
}
```

Response: `{"success":true}`

Next, to login as that user:

```
POST /api/v2/user/session
X-DreamFactory-Api-Key: 0d430cc287b5dd88b0f615d2bb69d84ba7201e8d4214fee2eabcc96bcd937d7d

{
  "email": "user@domain.com",
  "password": "password"
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "session_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsInVzZXJfaWQiOjMsImZvcmV2ZXIiOmZhbHNlLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvZGVtby5lbnRlcnByaXNlLmRyZWFtZmFjdG9yeS5jb21cL2FwaVwvdjJcL3VzZXJcL3Nlc3Npb24iLCJpYXQiOiIxNDQ0Njc1NDU0IiwiZXhwIjoiMTQ0NDY3OTA1NCIsIm5iZiI6IjE0NDQ2NzU0NTQiLCJqdGkiOiIyMjFiYTg5M2E2YTc4OThlNDdlZGI4MGY5YjVkY2M2ZCJ9.V8y2B_2vlh8QdFhRqyuSG8SbfIVe8g71RvNjKoW2Bi8",
  "session_id":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsInVzZXJfaWQiOjMsImZvcmV2ZXIiOmZhbHNlLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvZGVtby5lbnRlcnByaXNlLmRyZWFtZmFjdG9yeS5jb21cL2FwaVwvdjJcL3VzZXJcL3Nlc3Npb24iLCJpYXQiOiIxNDQ0Njc1NDU0IiwiZXhwIjoiMTQ0NDY3OTA1NCIsIm5iZiI6IjE0NDQ2NzU0NTQiLCJqdGkiOiIyMjFiYTg5M2E2YTc4OThlNDdlZGI4MGY5YjVkY2M2ZCJ9.V8y2B_2vlh8QdFhRqyuSG8SbfIVe8g71RvNjKoW2Bi8",
  "id":3,
  "name":"Basic User",
  "first_name":"Basic",
  "last_name":"User",
  "email":"user@domain.com",
  "is_sys_admin":false,
  "last_login_date":"2015-10-12 18:44:14",
  "host":"console",
  "role":"basic",
  "role_id":1
}
```

Since you tried using basic auth, I did too:

```
GET /api/v2/db
X-DreamFactory-Api-Key: 0d430cc287b5dd88b0f615d2bb69d84ba7201e8d4214fee2eabcc96bcd937d7d
Authorization: Basic dXNlckBkb21haW4uY29tOnBhc3N3b3Jk
```

Response:

```
{
  "resource": 
    [
      {"name":"_schema"},
      {"name":"_table"},
      {"name":"_proc"},
      {"name":"_func"}
    ]
}
```

Docs for DreamFactory 2.0: http://wiki.dreamfactory.com/DreamFactory/API

In-depth docs for each possible API call may be found in the API Docs tab of a DreamFactory instance. API Docs are automatically generated and self-documenting, using [Swagger UI](http://blog.dreamfactory.com/blog/bid/294825/Why-We-Like-Swagger-for-API-Docs).